# Netbeans does not show error messages

Tags: php, netbeans

Helo,
my Netbeans does not show error messages when some error occurred in code. It used to show red icon on the line where error (eg. syntax error) occurred. Now it shows icon only next to filename in file tab. I do not remember if I changed some IDE settings - there was no reason to disable error messages.

[image: Not showing error message on the line 85]

I expect red icon on the line number 85, like it is here

[image]

Maybe I am missing some option in netbeans preferences. I have tried to find it but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't apply to OP because they are using .php extensions, but it might help someone else...

For me the issue was because I'm developing with drupal and so most files don't end with php. To fix my issue:

1. Tools | Options | Miscellaneous | Files
2. Click New next to File Extension and choose 'text/x-php5' as the associated file type.
3. Restart IDE

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have fixed the problem, but I had the same issue here.
I finally successed in fixing it.

In "Tools" > "Options" > "Editor tab", then in "Hints" tab, I disabled the "Braces" section for PHP language.

I don't know why, but now syntax errors are shown in the left side bar as your screenshot shows.

I hope this can help you!

EDIT: I'm using Netbeans v8.1 for Linux.